# Why is the RT invariant from $\mathcal Z(\mathcal C)$ the (norm) square of the one from $\mathcal C$?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, topological-quantum-field-theory

The relationship between Turaev-Viro/state-sum invariants and Reshetikhin-Turaev/surgery invariants is roughly that
$$\tau_{TV, \mathcal C}(M) = |\tau_{RT, \mathcal C}(M)|^2.$$
Here $\mathcal C$ is a modular category.
More generally, we have
$$\tau_{TV, \mathcal C} = \tau_{RT, \mathcal C} \otimes \bar \tau_{RT, \mathcal C},$$
where $\bar \tau_{RT, \mathcal C}$ is the "mirror" theory where you take opposite orientations.
One way to prove this is via careful analysis of the state-sums and how they relate to surgery presentations of your manifold, as in Turaev's book.

On the other hand, if we instead start with a spherical fusion category $\mathcal C$ (weaker than being a modular category: in particular, there doesn't need to be a braiding on $\mathcal C$) is is known that
$$\tau_{TV, \mathcal C} = \tau_{RT, \mathcal Z(\mathcal C)}$$
where $\mathcal Z(\mathcal C)$ is the Drinfeld center. This is an equivalence of 3-2-1 TQFTs.

Presumably this means that if I have a modular category $\mathcal C$, then

$$\tau_{RT, \mathcal Z(\mathcal C)} = \tau_{RT, \mathcal C} \otimes \bar \tau_{RT, \mathcal C} $$
Is this true? Is there a way to see this equivalence without factoring through the TV theory? It would be enough for me to understand this just for links in $S^3$, not necessarily the full TQFT.

Comment: If $C$ is modular, in particular it is factorizable so that $Z(C)$ is braided equivalent to $C \boxtimes \bar C$ where $\boxtimes$ is an appropriate tensor product and $\bar C$ is $C$ with opposite tensor product and inverse braiding. I feel it shouldn't be hard to show in general that $\tau_{C \boxtimes \bar C}$ is $\tau_C \otimes \bar \tau_C$, and this is clearly true for links in $S^3$.

Comment: Why is $Z(C)$ braided equivalent to $C \boxtimes \bar C$? Do you know a reference that might discuss this in more detail?

Comment: This is one of the several equivalent definitions of modularity/factorizability, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06534 for a proof in the more general non-necessarily semisimple case and references for the semisimple one. Note also that in the semisimple case the definition of $\boxtimes$ is much easier.

Comment: Or https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111205 for an older school proof in the semisimple case.